# Reading java file with escape characters for newline

Tags: java, escaping, bufferedreader, unicode-escapes

I have a Unicode file that needs to be exported to database(Vertica). The column delimiter is CTRL+B, record delimiter is newline(\n). Whenever there is a newline within a column value, CTRL+A is used as escape character.

When I use BufferedReader.readLine() to read this file, the records with ID's 2 and 4, are read as two records. Whereas I want to read them as a single whole record as given in output.

Here is the example input file. | stands for CTRL+B and ^ stands for CTRL+A.

```
Input
ID|Name|Job Desc
----------------
1|xxxx|SO Job
2|YYYY|SO Careers^
Job
3|RRRRR|SO
4|ZZZZ^
 ZZ|SO Job
5|AAAA|YU

Output:
ID|Name|Job Desc
----------------
1|xxxx|SO Job
2|YYYY|SO Careers Job
3|RRRRR|SO
4|ZZZZ ZZ|SO Job
5|AAAA|YU
```

The file is huge, so I cant use StringEscapeUtils. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Read the input file and output in a different format?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: I am trying to read file and get prepared statements. I would like the file to be read as it were in format as in output.

Comment: According to the documentation for `BufferedReader.readLine()`, only `\n` or `\r\n` are treated as new lines.  Your records 2 and 4 should _not_ be getting read as 2 separate lines.

Comment: The job desc values on 2&4 are separated by newline and Ctrl+a is used as escape character. So it reads them as two lines

Comment: You can use a `Scanner` with a custom delimeter set to not match `CTRL+A` followed by `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Scanner` with a custom delimeter.  The delimeter I use is set to match `\n` but **not** `\u0001\n` (where `\u0001` represents `CTRL+A`):

```
try {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("dboutput.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("dbinput.txt"));
    sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("^(?!.*(\\u0001\\n)).*\\n$"));
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        writer.println(sc.next());
    }
    scanner.close();
    writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Tim, yours does not resolve newlines escaped by CTRL+A. But, I have selected this as this is close and led to me right answer. Can you also explain your regex please. Thanks

Comment: The regex matches `\n` but not when it occurs as `\u0001\n`.  So the newlines in the middle of your records would be treated as text.

Answer (score 0):

[Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29909131/1970734) is partially right in his answer. But, it still does not resolve newlines escaped by CTRL+A.

Here is my solution for that(guided by [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29909131/1970734) answer)

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\SV7104\\Desktop\\sampletest.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\s*\\u0002\\n\\s*"));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(1);
                System.out.println(sc.next().toString().replaceAll("\\u0001\\n", " "));

            }
```

If there's some other efficient method, I am curious to know about that too.

Comment: In your answer you are using a delimeter of `\u0002\n` but you then replace `\u0001\n` with a space.  I think you could have just called `replaceAll` directly on the whole input.