# Need more efficient java.util.scanner

Tags: java

I have a block of java code I'm trying to run, it looks like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

File f = new File("input.tsv");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("^(?!.*(\\\\\\n)).*\\n$"));

import java.io.PrintWriter;
Writer writer = new PrintWriter("output.tsv");
while (scanner.hasNext())
    writer.println(scanner.next().toString().replaceAll("\\\\\\n", ""));

scanner.close();
writer.close();
```

This uses a pile of memory and seems very inefficient to basically patch incoming files and remove escaped new line characters.

**There has to be a better way ?!** Surely NIO or something can steam in and stream out etc.

PS. The above was stolen from this thread here:
[Reading java file with escape characters for newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908236/reading-java-file-with-escape-characters-for-newline)

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Why use a Scanner at all instead of reading in the whole file in one go and doing the replacement all in one go?

Comment: And why use a regex when you want to replace a literal substring? Use replace(), not replaceAll().

Comment: Even simply reading line-by-line would save cycles. For efficient i/o, look into setting the block size.